# How to convert Datetime for machine learning

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to feed datetime as dependent variable(y) for linear regression.

```
train = data.iloc[:, :1].values
test = data.iloc[:, -1].values

print(train)

array([['2013-04-14T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2013-04-15T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2013-04-16T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ...,
       ['2019-06-03T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2019-06-04T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2019-06-05T00:00:00.000000000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I am fitting the train and test values into the model.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, test, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
```

I am getting the error below:

```
---> 12 y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

How can I feed datetime into the model. I do not want to encode datetime using label encoder unless absolutely required.